# Removing controls in a loop results in a strange behaviour

Tags: c#, button, controls

I'm having some weird behaviour when I try to remove all my dynamically allocated buttons.

I give each of these buttons the same name as in "dynamicButton"

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    foreach (Control item in Controls.OfType<Control>())
    {
         if (item.Name.Contains("dynamicButton"))
             {
                 Controls.Remove(item);
             }
    }
}
```

Notice the that it loops this 10 times (though 6 or 7 would be enough).
Below I'll show you how it does things.

[At i=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE54X.png)

[At i=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMzU6.png)

[At i=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFyAm.png)

[At i=3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXBfd.png)

And so on until they all dissapear.

As shown, I'm making a lot of unecessary loops inside this thing, and for some reason it doesn't take the all out even though I'm using the same parameter going in...

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why you use `Controls.OfType<Control>` and not `Controls.OfType<Button>`

Comment: I guess I could've done that, there are only like 5 controls total out of 250ish that isn't a button, so I'm not really gaining anything by doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're modifying the collection while looping over it. Some collection types (like `List<T>`) have built-in "protection" against this, throwing an exception on the next iteration, but `ControlCollection` apparently doesn't.

Say you're at element #4 and you remove it - element #5 will then move to #4, causing it to be skipped.

You could reverse the loop, ie:

```
for (int i = Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Control item = Controls[i];
    if (item.Name.Contains("dynamicButton"))
    {
        Controls.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: best answer, cant beleive the other suggestions to make a list - totally unnecessary.  (Linq is not always the best, in those cases definitely worse.)

Comment: This does not work if Controls is a collection (i.e. non-indexable) - it also does not work if controls is not entirely composed of controls, which is strongly suggested in the OPs post.

Comment: @AdamBrown `ControlCollection` implements `IList` and can only contain objects that derive from `Control`

Comment: @AdamBrown: the `OfType<Control>` doesn't make sense in OP's code because there are only controls, he could use `Cast<Control>` safely(f.e. to  use LINQ). But the question is why he didn't use `OfType` to filter for only `Button`. So use  `OfType<Button>` instead.

Comment: I don't see that the OfType<> gains much, and the same filtering could be done here. var item = Controls[i] as Button; if (item?.Name.Contains("dynamicButton") == true) ...

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the explaination! Appriciate it!